# what is wrong with my http request

Tags: node.js, http, request

I am able to enter my url : 192.168.1.132 into my browser and I get proper response with "hello world",  same thing if I do a curl 192.168.1.132

but if I run this code

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'http://192.168.1.132',
  path: '/'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
  console.log(str);
```

I get error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://192.168.1.132
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Host should not include the protocol; just `192.168.1.132`

Comment: without protocol, I get similar error events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Error (native)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:310:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)

Answer (score 0):

The only error discernible from the code you've shown is the inclusion of the protocol scheme in the `host` property of your `options` object. That should just be:

```
host: '192.168.1.132',
```

Any further errors that occur after that change are in code that you have not shown. Here is a sample of working code based on your code.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  path: '/index.html'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
};

var req = http.request(options, callback);

req.on('error', function (e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: trott, I tried your code with edited host without protocol, I got a "Parse Error"  My server is running nodeMCU with the statement "conn:on("<h1>Hello World </h1>")  Does the output need to be in a certain format?